# Water flow at different heights

Tags: water, fluid-statics

I'm trying to build an irrigation system for my plants, using only gravity (no pump). It would look like this:

```
|~~~|
|   |  <--- water tank
\___/
  |
  |      o  <--- pipe opening A
  |      |             
  |      |      o  <--- pipe opening B
  |      |      |
  \------/------/
```

Would the amount of water coming out of pipe opening A be larger than for pipe opening B because its position is higher? If so, how can this be calculated (assuming all pipes have the same diameter)?

UPDATE Furthermore, if pipe opening B were to be closed, would this affect the flow through A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE velocities of water coming out will be different. The smaller height pipe will eject water with more velocity. You can find the velocity by using Bernoulli's equation.